# Unable to post comment on someone else's Facebook Album in the same group using Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

I am creating a new album using:

```
$album_post = array(
            "message" => $messageToPost,
            'name' => 'Album name'
        );
Facebook::post('/' . $Facebook_Group_Id . '/albums', $album_post, $longToken)
```

Here longToken is generated using following:

```
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id=" . env('FB_ID') . "&client_secret=" . env('FB_SEC')."&fb_exchange_token=$user->fb_access_token";

$longToken = file_get_contents($url);
parse_str($longToken, $lToken);
$longToken = $lToken['access_token'];
```

It has created the album successfully.
Now I want to post a new comment on that album. But I am unable to do that. I am using following code:

```
$post = array(
  "message" => $comment
 );
Facebook::post('/' . $albumOwner->fb_user_id . '_' . $album_id . '/comments', $post, $longToken)->getDecodedBody();
```

It is posting the comment if album owner/author is trying to post the comment. 
But if someone else try to post comment on the same album, its giving error.

E.g I am **Mr. W** and my friend is **Mr. Z.**

We both joined a group.

Mr. W created a new album in that group and posted photos into that. Now Mr. Z came into group and saw that album, he can post comment on Facebook. But if Mr. Z try to post comment using Graph API, using the method posted above, application gives following error:

```
FacebookResponseException in FacebookResponseException.php line 111: An unknown error occurred
```

I have also tried in Graph API explorer, it works If I use Mr. W access token, but cannot post comment if I use Mr. Z's access token.

Using following FB permissions:

```
['publish_actions', 'email', 'user_location', 'user_hometown', 'user_birthday', 'user_photos']
```

these are for both Mr. W and Mr. Z. Same permissions for both of them.

Please help, or clarify if its not possible using graph API.

Comment: What permissions does your user access token for Z include?

Comment: ['publish_actions', 'email', 'user_location', 'user_hometown', 'user_birthday', 'user_photos'] these are for both Mr. W and Mr. Z. Same permissions for both of them.

Comment: @CBroe : wts up :) any solution?

Comment: If this was an error on your part, then at least you should get an error message telling you what’s actually wrong, and not just “an unknown error occurred” – so I suggest you go file a bug report, https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else trying to fix this issue, please note that its a bug.
I have reported it and Facebook Team accepted it as a valid bug. 
Here is the bug URL: 
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1007044002691354/